# return type of function inferred incorrectly if the return statement is outside a switch statement

Tags: typescript

given

```
const ACTION_1 = "ACTION_1";
type ACTION_1 = "ACTION_1";

const ACTION_2 = "ACTION_2";
type ACTION_2 = "ACTION_2";

type ActionTypes = 
  | ACTION_1
  | ACTION_2

export type Reducer<S = any> = (
  state: S | undefined,
  action: ActionTypes
) => S
```

when I have this Reducer:

```
const reducer: Reducer<boolean> = (
  state = false,
  action
) => {
  switch (action) {
    case ACTION_1:
       return true;
    case ACTION_2:
       return false;
    default:
  }
  return state;
}
```

**in strict mode** it complains that this function has a return type of `IState | undefined` but when I swap the `return state;` at the end for a `default: return state` in the switch statement it is fine. Or even just an empty `default:` and leaving the return statement at the bottom will, placate the compiler.

With the return type it even recognises in vscode that the return statement is unreachable. I understand it has to take it into account because run time it doesn't know if the switch statement was actually exhaustive.

But even if I have the default, it does know the return is definitely unreachable and still it complains about the fact this function could return `IState | undefined`.

And even that is wrong because there's a default value for the `state` parameter. So it is never undefined.

Is this a bug? Or a known limitation?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggYQCoEkDyA5A+gRhgXhgCJFVNciBuAKCgE8AHAU3mXWz0JLfJyuuqhIsUuywAmAsVHlx-es1ZlskrjJX9ajFnGBQAluCTaIU6jBgAfJWJzmrN2QKYAPBiABOsBSwBKTABMAV2AmDwAeAGUpAEMwOgA+KQAKe2gYqCYALhho6yCwAKYAM30wQIAaexi9QzAc3QMjE2oASgIkyIEhaBgPQJCwnP9g0IiAIxAQABsmOKTCVIt0zKlimOmIJiqLGqawNo6YAG80gHd9KGAACxhkvbr204sLYBitxw4s+xeLfqggh4wDAoB4gkwaL83h91BJvr8Xv9AcD1psIT8YEV1kFplB4TAAL72JFAmArdEEoA)

Comment: You allow state to be undefined due to your `Reducer` type (  `state: S | undefined,`), I assume this is what typescripts discovers. If you work with a default, why allow undefined?

Comment: I know but that's not the question, the question is why can't it infer that the result of this function in never `undefined`. When there is a return statement outside the switch statement. And it can infer it's never `undefined` when there is a default in the switch.

Comment: Which version of tyepscript do use? I can't recreate the error on  3.6.2.

Comment: Have you got `strict` turned on? I'm on 3.7.5.

Comment: Yes, I have strict enabled. Does the issue persist if you add a `default` case? (Just `default:`, you can let it fall through.)

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Using ts 3.7.5
Can you reproduce the issue in the code sandbox ?

Comment: added a link to playground showing the error

Comment: An empty `default:` label does fix the error; very strange. Looks like a bug.

Comment: @k0pernikus like I said if I have a default statement in the switch it's happy.

Comment: @albertjan As you said in the question, `default: return state;` works, but k0pernikus is pointing out that just `default:` without returning from within the `switch` also works.

Comment: Ok but my question still stands.

Comment: The answer seems to be that it's a bug in Typescript, because an empty `default:` label should have no effect but here we can see it does have an effect. I suggest trying to reduce it down to the shortest/simplest code that reproduces the behaviour, and posting an issue on the TS issue tracker: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: @albertjan Gotcha. It appears to be a typescript bug. I've searched through the existing issues, but did not find it being reported yet. So feel free to open one up. github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: I've distilled the problem down a bit will post an issue. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: just tried it on 3.9.0-dev and it's solved haha closing this question I guess.

Comment: I think it could possibly be this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in typescript version 3.8.